# How to add peer into exsiting network in hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am new to hyperledger fabric and trying some hands on. I am trying to add and joined the peer into the channel using fabric SDK but I am getting  ""[Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7088"" this error.

I have used addPeer function of channel and after addition I tried to join the peer to channel using join channel operation. But after running the code I got the error I mentioned above. If any one can suggest how to add and join the peer using fabric API.

```
import { FileSystemWallet, Gateway } from 'fabric-network';
import * as path from 'path';
import { Peer } from 'fabric-client';
import { request } from 'https';

const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'first-network', 'connection-org1.json');

async function main() {
    try {

        identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
        const userExists = await wallet.exists('user1');
        if (!userExists) {
            console.log('An identity for the user "user1" does not exist in the wallet');
            console.log('Run the registerUser.ts application before retrying');
            return;
        }


        const gateway = new Gateway();
        await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'user1', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });

        // Get the network (channel) our contract is deployed to.
        const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');

        var  opts ={
            name: 'peer4.org1.example.com',
            request_timeout: '5252',
            'pem': '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIICVzCCAf2gAwIBAgIQfdwd3s8+f0YvH2esgpia7TAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjB2MQsw\nCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNU2FuIEZy\nYW5jaXNjbzEZMBcGA1UEChMQb3JnMS5leGFtcGxlLmNvbTEfMB0GA1UEAxMWdGxz\nY2Eub3JnMS5leGFtcGxlLmNvbTAeFw0xOTEwMjIwNjA3MDBaFw0yOTEwMTkwNjA3\nMDBaMHYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQH\nEw1TYW4gRnJhbmNpc2NvMRkwFwYDVQQKExBvcmcxLmV4YW1wbGUuY29tMR8wHQYD\nVQQDExZ0bHNjYS5vcmcxLmV4YW1wbGUuY29tMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0D\nAQcDQgAEJBq3JFLV0LdNLxOBLS/BH1jh2AMjg6awzO5fz9faB0rIBj7xZg4sCwq4\nwA5M3y5kOjVDTZaEe/t+8o4DMZmBmaNtMGswDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgGmMB0GA1Ud\nJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMCBggrBgEFBQcDATAPBgNVHRMBAf8EBTADAQH/MCkGA1Ud\nDgQiBCB6UC4NGyvuVZ0Bmi7aWkju7bRm3jZvU9kNXrVgFeBa6TAKBggqhkjOPQQD\nAgNIADBFAiEArR3BiLVpA0z3K53wr+2Cjjtq0gmx2un9Nlgl352bhAoCIEh9dZCK\ny+JcrTBTWM57WZvmieVvf2uUN9UgJ2xHyK9o\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n',
            sslcerti: 'peer4.org1.example.com',
        }
        var peer =  new Peer('grpcs://localhost:7088', opts);

        var channel =  network.getChannel();

        channel.addPeer(peer,'Org1MSP')



        var request ={
            target:[peer],
            block :await channel.getGenesisBlock(),
            txId :gateway.getClient().newTransactionID(true)
        }

        channel.joinChannel(request, 5252)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7088** --> defines that it is trying to connect to server with respective port ,but it is failing .seems to be the service is not running or port is not properly bounded.
Make sure that either service is properly running or port is enabled.If any issue let me know

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying but I don't think port is an issue coz changing port number is the first thing I have  done, like just now I tried but got the same error.

Comment: check version of node npm 
fabric
node
npm
grpc
fabric-ca-client
fabric-client

remove the node_modules ,install and rebuild once again 

rm -rf node_modules
npm install
npm rebuild
 and then try

Comment: Done but getting same thing, can you please tell me my code is correct or not like the way I add peer to channel